# Symfony 4 setter injection not working in bundle with or without autowire

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, factory, autowired, symfony4

I thought I fully understood Symfony's autowiring behaviour, but there must be something I'm missing and I'm hoping someone can fill in the blanks.

Three questions to begin with:

- Is there a difference in the Symfony autowire behaviour in the main application vs in a bundle?
- If you ask Symfony to autowire bundle services, does it completely ignore service definitions in the bundles `services.yaml` file?
- Are there known issues with the setter injection functionality in Symfony 4?

I have a service definition within a bundle that uses setter injection but it seems to be completely ignored by Symfony, when I've asked Symfony to autowire my bundle services and even when I've asked Symfony to exclude services from the autowiring.

My application is using Symfony `v4.1.3`.

I have included my Bundle in my applications `bundles.php` file.

```
<?php

return [
  //... core bundles,
  Acme\\Symfony\\AcmeCustomBundle\\AcmeCustomBundle::class => ['all' => true] 
];
```

In the `default` Symfony application `services.yaml` file, I have asked Symfony to autowire my bundles services with the following:

```
Acme\Symfony\AcmeCustomBundle\:
    resource: '../vendor/acme-symfony/custom-bundle/*'
    exclude: '../vendor/acme-symfony/custom-bundle/{Model,Tests}'
```

In my bundles `services.yaml` file located in `../vendor/acme-symfony/custom-bundle/Resources/config/services.yaml`, I have the following:

```
parameters:

services:
    Acme\Symfony\AcmeCustomBundle\Search\ConfigurationReader:
      calls:
        - method: setIndex
          arguments:
            $index: '%elasticsearch.index%'
        - method: setSchema
          arguments:
            $schema: '%elasticsearch.schema%'
```

The parameters are set in my bundle extension class (extends configurable extension), and I have already verified that the parameters do exist and are getting set using the following method:

```
$container->setParameter('elasticsearch.index', $mergedConfigs['elasticsearch']['index']);
$container->setParameter('elasticsearch.schema', $mergedConfigs['elasticsearch']['schema']);
```

Now back to the problem. Symfony is not performing the setter injection, even when I tell Symfony to not autowire the above service by doing the following:

```
 Acme\Symfony\AcmeCustomBundle\:
    resource: '../vendor/acme-symfony/custom-bundle/*'
    exclude: '../vendor/acme-symfony/custom-bundle/{Model,Tests,Search}'
```

I did however get Symfony to configure my service when I

- Turned off the autowiring for the above service
- Used the factory method of service creation

This kind of answered my second question above, but I'm not 100% sure of it. Nonetheless, I would much rather not have to use a factory class just to get around what may be an issue with Symfony, or my lack of understanding of how the setter injection / autowiring really work.

Can anyone see something obvious that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, autowiring in bundles that are meant to be shared is not part of the best practices. You must explicitly define the services of a bundle you are going to share, and doing it in xml.

Now, that being said, what autowire does is that wires up the services in the constructor of a class, trying to autoresolve them. It does not perform setter injection.

What you need is to do is to configure an auto-cofiguration entry. In your bundle extension class, you can do:

```
$container->registerForAutoconfiguration(ConfigurationReader::class)
    ->addMethodCall('setIndex', ['%elasticsearch.index%'])
    ->addMethodCall('setSchema', ['%elasticsearch.schema%']);
```

Now, this is really meant to be used with interfaces or abstract classes, not really with concrete implementations. But is what you can do if you want to autoconfigure your service.

My suggestion is, if you are going to reuse this bundle, to define the services explicitly and in xml. Autowiring is for your business logic and services.

Comment: Good to know that autowiring doesn't do setter injection, if that was in the official documentation, I must have missed it. My bundles are private, the core functionality doesn't change across my applications and I've exposed configuration for anything that needs to, so I autowire as much as possible for convenience really (but I know the best practice!) I've used the "register auto configuration" concept for logger injection in controllers although my injector was a service. Useful to know I can do it in the extension. Any reason why you recommend defining services in xml and not yaml?

Comment: Better autocompletion and avoiding annoying yaml PHP storm issues

Comment: Also, shorter service definitions

Comment: Those sound like valid reasons, although I've always personally preferred yaml to xml. Time will tell if I can be drawn away from that!

Comment: I do think that yaml is easier to understand though.

Comment: Also, how come you are using setter injection for these parameters? Can the service be used without those values being set?

Answer (score 9):

You can autowire other methods (e.g. Setters) if you want, just by using the **@required** annotation in your service:

```
/**
 * @required
 */
public function setFoo(FooInterface $foo)
{
    $this->foo = $foo;
}
```

[Autowiring other methods](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#autowiring-other-methods-e-g-setters)

Comment: You should mark this as the correct answer @onetimeengineer

Comment: @MatíasNavarroCarter just seen this. This is a useful tip to know, but I tend not to use annotations with Symfony to trigger functionality, so I still consider your answer to be the correct one for me.

Comment: I just saw that answer and it seems to solve an issue I had with Compiler Pass that didn't use a setter. Is it something with the Symfony config that this annotation force to use.

Comment: @SelaYair you can take a look at *Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\AutowireRequiredMethodsPass*